# LIRC: "irw" doesn't work, but "irrecord" does

Tags: ubuntu, infrared, lirc

I've got an [Antec Fusion V2](http://www.antec.com/Believe_it/product.php?Type=Mg==&id=NTA=) chassis with a built in ir receiver.

I've setup lirc on my system, and I can get `irrecord` to see my remote input and build a config file.

I **cannot** get `irw` to work, and subsequently no activity on my HTPC.

I'm running [XBMC Live](http://xbmc.org/)

**Further Reading:**
I've asked two questions on the Live community forum, however it's a slow process and the helpful responses have only taken me so far. These threads include some debug logs and troubleshooting steps.

[Question 1](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=93279)
[Question 2](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=93899)

I'm wondering if this is something really basic that might simply be missing. The biggest problem here is that Linux changes so fast that information that was valid a year ago is completely obsolete now.

Thanks in advance.